# Looking for a Mussar Sefer broken into short daily teachings

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mussar-ethics

Looking for a recommendation on a mussar Sefer that has daily teachings, sort of like how the Chofetz Chaim Sefer was broken down into one page a day.

Not any specific type of mussar, but something meant to help grow, and something that has a daily agenda.

Comment: Check out cheshbon Hanefesh

Comment: Just so I understand where you are coming from. Why not take a classical musar text (e.g., Mesilat Yesharim, Shaarei Hatshuva) and learning for a fixed period (say 10-15 minutes a day)? Does a daily agenda really help you? The best sefer for you might not have a daily agenda so I want to understand. Also it would help if you shared what other musar sefer, if any, you learned already.

Comment: @mbloch Great question. I guess I figured a fixed agenda is better than my own breaking up. But you have a very good point.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a classic text, Tomer Devorah was broken up into a month of very doable pieces.

If you want amore of a middos workbook organized into a year of work for each day, I could recommend Every Day Holy Day by Dr Alan Morinis. (Although I was a researcher on the project, to be up-front about my biases.)

Comment: Thanks for the info! And thank you for letting me know about your work; can I message you about the Dr. Morinis book?

Comment: Sure. Or you could email me at micha at aishdas.org

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Orchot Chaim L'HaRosh.

Comment: This answer would be stronger if you explained why

Answer (score 0):

I love Zelig Pliskin's English books. They're very easy to set it up for daily use. I think that his book Gateway to Happiness is amazing.